# ReportLab not working on Azure Python website

Tags: python, django, azure, reportlab

I have build a very simple application on Python 3.4, Django 1.7.3 with PTVS in Visual Studio. Locally everything fine but when I publish to Azure Python website I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File ".\app\views.py", line 69, in home rml2pdf.go(rml, outputFileName=buf) File "rlextra-3.1.45/src/rlextra/rml2pdf/rml2pdf.py", line 5638, in go ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Most importantly `DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`. Here is my code,

```
try:
    from io import BytesIO
    buf = BytesIO()
    rml2pdf.go(rml, outputFileName=buf)
    buf.seek(0)
    pdfData = buf.read()
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response.write(pdfData)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
    return response
except:
    response = HttpResponse()
    response.write(traceback.format_exc())
    return response
```

I have changed 32bit to 64 bit from Azure portal but no luck.

Comment: How did you install reportlab into the virtualenv of your PTVS project? Please add more code and more about the structure of your project, like any Microsoft PTVS tutorial.

Comment: There are two options: I recreate your project structure and experience same errors and give advice or I advice on given information about project structure and code. I would prefer seconds approach first.

Comment: Make sure reportlab is installed - if you are using virtualenv, make sure you have virtualenv's python activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed all steps at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-create-deploy-django-app/. Now its working. The problem may be with publishing.